# Exclude a long list of values from a select query without having to use "?" for each placeholder

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

I am trying to automate the exclusion of several hundred values in a CSV from a SQL query using Python. I am converting the values in the CSV into a list, and then I am using "cursor.execute(statement, exclusion()" where statement is each query in my .sql file and exclusion is the list of values from the CSV.  Currently I need to use a "?" placeholder in the .sql file for each of the hundreds of values in my list, and I am trying to find a way to do this without having to use so many placeholders as the list will change weekly. Below is the full code that I am using.

```
 # converts the values in the CSV into a list:
 
 def exclusion():
     repeat_exclusion_df = pd.read_csv('repeat_names.csv')
     names_list = list(repeat_exclusion_df['names'])
     return names_list
 
 
 # I am using the following to read the .sql file and turn it into a pandas dataframe:
 
 import pandas as pd
 import logging
 
 cursor = connection_sql(uid=arguments.company_uid,
                         pwd=arguments.company_pwd,
                         server=arguments.company_server,
                         db=arguments.company_db)
 with open('names_query.sql') as sql_file:
     logging.info('Open sql file')
     df_list = []
     for statement in sql_file.read().split(';'):
         db_cursor = cursor.execute(statement, exclusion())
         logging.info('Read each sql query')
         if db_cursor is not None:
             results = db_cursor.fetchall()
             if results:
                 df = pd.DataFrame(results)
                 df.columns = results[0].keys()
                 df_list.append(df)
 
 # the following is a sample from the .sql file:
 SELECT NAME
 FROM [DATABASE]
 WHERE NAME NOT IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,)
```

Comment: Load the codes to exclude in a table and then you can exclude with a simple `[NOT] EXISTS` operator.

Comment: @The Impaler  Unfortunately I am not able to create a table in this situation.

Comment: You can use a temporary table.

Comment: The sample looks like it is T-SQL for Microsoft SQL Server. Is that what you are using? If so, what version?

Comment: @ Gord Thompson Yes, I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe I have never created a temporary table before. Is that something that's done within my Python IDE or Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: That ends in a question mark, but essentially you are saying "teach me databases". That is not in the scope of a Stackoverflow question. You can easily find out about temporary tables from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft SQL Server, a table whose name starts with `#` is a temporary table.

```py
import io

import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

engine = create_engine(
    URL.create(
        "mssql+pyodbc",
        username="scott",
        password="tiger^5HHH",
        host="192.168.0.199",
        database="test",
        query=dict(driver="ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"),
    ),
    fast_executemany=True,
)

# create example environment
insp = inspect(engine)
if not insp.has_table("main_table"):
    with engine.begin() as conn:
        conn.exec_driver_sql(
            "CREATE TABLE main_table (name nvarchar(50) primary key)"
        )
        conn.exec_driver_sql(
            "INSERT INTO main_table (name) VALUES "
            "(N'Alfa'), (N'Bravo'), (N'Charlie'), (N'Delta')"
        )
        print("Table created: main_table")

# read exclusion list from CSV
repeat_names_csv = io.StringIO(
    """\
name
Bravo
Delta
"""
)
repeat_exclusion_df = pd.read_csv(repeat_names_csv)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    # upload DataFrame to #temporary table
    repeat_exclusion_df.to_sql(
        "#exclusions", conn, if_exists="replace", index=False
    )
    select_query = """\
    SELECT name FROM main_table
    WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM #exclusions)
    """
    results = conn.exec_driver_sql(select_query).all()
    print(results)  # [('Alfa',), ('Charlie',)]
```